# R - cortar dígitos

Tags: r

Alguém saberia me dizer, como consigo cortar dígitos no R?

Exemplo:

```
ano <- c(1999,2000,2001,2002,2003)
```

E que retornasse apenas:

```
#[1] 99 00 01 02 03
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Podemos usar a funcao `substr` fazendo o seguinte:

```
ano<- c(1999,2000,2001,2002,2003)

substr(ano, 3, 4)
```

resultado:

```
[1] "99" "00" "01" "02" "03"
```

O que a função `substr` faz?

A função tem 3 argumentos:

> `substr(x, start, stop)`

`x` é o vetor que você desejar cortar os dígitos. Tenha em mente que o vetor que você definiu (`ano`) é do tipo `double`. Nesse caso, a função `substr` vai transformar `ano` em `character` para efetuar a operação.

`start`: aonde vai começar a cortar os dígitos? A posição inicial do corte. Por exemplo `substr("sport recife", 1, 1,)` retornará `"s"`.

`end`: seguindo a mesma idéia, essa é o último dígito que será incluido no corte.

Comment: Muito obrigada! Era isso que precisava. Tinha encontrado essa função "str_sub(ano, start = -2)", mas não funcionou aqui.

Comment: @iara Eu não sei por que não funcionou, mas desconfio que você não instalou (ou não carregou) o pacote `stringr`. Tenta isso: `stringr::str_sub(ano, -2)`. Se não funcionar, é por que você não tem o pacote instalado. Instale e repita o código, deve funcionar.

Comment: Sim, acredito que seja pela falta do pacote mesmo. Aqui tenho algumas restrições quanto a instalação de novos pacotes. Mas funcionou com a sua dica. Muito obrigada @JdeMello!

Answer (score 5):

Apesar de já haver uma resposta aceite, aqui vai outra maneira de fazer o mesmo.

Pode-se usar aritmética para ficar só com os dois últimos algarismos, basta calcular o resto da divisão pela potência de dez apropriada.

```
ano %% 100
#[1] 99  0  1  2  3
```

Ou, se for preciso um resultado com 2 algarismos, formatar com `sprintf`, por exemplo.

```
sprintf("%02d", ano %% 100)
#[1] "99" "00" "01" "02" "03"
```

E isto pode ser posto numa função mais geral.

```
cortar <- function(x, digits = 2, numeric = FALSE){
  y <- x %% 10^digits
  if(numeric)
    y
  else{
    fmt <- paste0("%0", digits, "d")
    sprintf(fmt, y)
  }
}

cortar(ano)
#[1] "99" "00" "01" "02" "03"

cortar(ano, digits = 3)
#[1] "999" "000" "001" "002" "003"

cortar(ano, numeric = TRUE)
#[1] 99  0  1  2  3
```